# Visual Studio 2013 Unable to Start Program

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I have a problem when starting the debugger. When I press the Play button I receive a message

> Unable to start program:
>
> D:.......................\MyApp.exe

Then I did "Start without debugging", which happens without problems. And after that I tried "Attach to Process" to MyApp.exe, but no success; it gives a message:

> Unable to attach to process.

It happens both in Debug and Release builds; both are 64 bits.

I even tried to clean the (BIG!) whole source tree, and let the computer building it all overnight.

This morning, I tried the same thing, but no success still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague came with a very simple suggestion, an idea that didn't come to my mind: Restart Visual Studio!

And it worked!